# Running insecure Docker registry in k8s pod

Tags: docker, docker-registry, kubernetes

Docker registry:2.6.2 on k8s v1.9

Insecure registry runs in pod successfully and is accessible though service nodePort outside of k8s with added edit:
{ "insecure-registries":["xx.xx.xx.xxx:30002"] } 
to /etc/docker/daemon.json file, but can't pull images from within k8s:

Failed to pull image "registry.default.svc.cluster.local/elasticsearch:6.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown 
desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.default.svc.cluster.local/v1/_ping: Proxy Authentication Required

This is the same error outside of k8s when docker daemon doesn't know it is an insecure registry.